# grub shows same linux image twice

Tags: grub2

After a recent update, I get multiple entries for same linux kernel version in the boot menu. I have tried running `update-grub2` but it also lists the same linux-image version twice i.e

```
adnan@adnan-laptop:/boot$ sudo update-grub2
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-26-generic
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-26-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

As you can see vmlinuz and initrd are found multiple times. But there is only one vmlinuz and initrd file in /boot

```
adnan@adnan-laptop:/boot$ ls -l
total 15120
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  646144 2010-11-24 15:58 abi-2.6.32-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  110601 2010-11-24 15:58 config-2.6.32-26-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 2011-01-01 18:59 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8335528 2010-12-20 23:36 initrd.img-2.6.32-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  160280 2010-03-23 14:40 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2156100 2010-11-24 15:58 System.map-2.6.32-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1336 2010-11-24 16:00 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4050080 2010-11-24 15:58 vmlinuz-2.6.32-26-generic
```

Can some one tell me why does update-grub2 finds vmlinuz and initrd twice? and how to stop this from happening.

**UPDATE**: Find grub.cfg [here](http://pastebin.com/Dkk5vN7q)

Comment: The command is `update-grub` and not `update-grub2` i guess.Could you post the contents of **grub.cfg** ? Also have you created any custom grub files in `/etc/grub.d` ?

Comment: @karthick87 `update-grub2` is just a wrapper for `update-grub`, so it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Thankyou  @htorque i have never used that command,that is why i am confused.

Comment: binW, I think you have to run: `ls -la /etc/grub.d`, because you may have there two **##_linux** file. These scripts looks for OS-s when you update grub. Update your question with that output!

Comment: Yes. After posting the grub.cfg file I analysed it my self too and found that there are two *_linux files. So I changed permission for 10_linux to not-executable. After that I ran update-grub and it fixed the problem but I still dont know how I got two ##_linux files there. I didnt have that problem before the update.

Comment: Ok, than who will anwser? :) I can... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I thought, you had two linux image finder in `/etc/grub.d`, remove one, the right list is:

```
00_header 
05_debian_theme 
10_linux 
20_memtest86+ 
30_os-prober 
40_custom
```

These scripts looks for OS-s when you update the grub.