# update-grub shows three images?

Tags: grub2

When I'm running `update-grub` get following output:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Why are there three images listed?

I've read "[grub shows same linux image twice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19635/grub-shows-same-linux-image-twice)" too. This hasn't solved my problem.

---

Content of my /etc/grub.d/ is:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7541 okt 14 19:36 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5488 okt  4 11:30 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10891 okt 14 19:36 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10258 okt 14 19:36 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1688 okt 11 16:10 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10976 okt 14 19:36 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1426 okt 14 19:36 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 okt 14 19:36 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 okt 14 19:36 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 okt 14 19:36 README
```

Comment: where is three times? I see different kernel images.. 17, 25 & 26. Newer kernels get installed on updating the system.

Comment: My fault, rephrasing.. I meant why 3 images are listed.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find this by some googling:

```
current=`uname -r` && uninstall="" && for version in `dpkg -l linux-image* | grep ii | awk '{ print $2}'`; do if [[ "$version" < "linux-image-$current" ]]; then uninstall=$uninstall" $version"; fi; done && sudo apt-get purge $uninstall -y && sudo update-grub2
```

It removes old kernels and updates grub. This solved my problem.