# Why does 'update-grub' detect kernels twice?

Tags: grub2

When updating my GRUB config files (e.g. automatically after kernel updates), I get an output mentioning all Linux kernels (both the `vmlinuz` and `initrd` file) twice:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-19-generic
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-19-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

The GRUB boot menu does not show any duplicate entries though.

After reading [grub shows same linux image twice](https://askubuntu.com/q/19635/367990) (which is from 2011/01/01!), I checked my list of executable scripts in `/etc/grub.d`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  9791 Okt 14 18:36 00_header*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6058 Sep  4 13:13 05_debian_theme*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   618 Okt 30 12:59 10_linux_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   229 Okt 30 12:59 30_os-prober_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   621 Okt 30 12:59 33_linux_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11082 Okt 14 18:36 34_linux_xen*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   294 Okt 30 12:59 35_memtest86+_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1418 Okt 14 18:36 36_uefi-firmware*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   322 Okt 30 12:59 40_custom_proxy*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   216 Okt 14 18:36 41_custom*
```

As the answer in the linked question shows only a short list of 6 scripts, which are mostly named differently, I assume that it is either outdated or that I am just a special case...

However, I could not spot two identical files, as `10_linux_proxy` and `33_linux_proxy` have similar names, but different file sizes.

- Now, why do I get duplicate messages for all Linux kernels in the `update-grub` output and how do I fix it?
- Do I need to delete one of the `*_linux_proxy` files? If yes, which one?
- And what could have initially caused this problem?

#### UPDATE:

I have just disabled the execution permission of `33_linux_proxy` and ran `update-grub`. It looked correct, as there was only one occurrence of each kernel version and file in the output. So I rebooted, but there was *no Ubuntu entry at all any more*!
I managed to reset the configuration and am now back in the same situation as before.

Should I try disabling the other one (`10_linux_proxy`) now? I am not really looking forward to restore the old configuration through a live session again if it fails...

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem before, and the extra kernels didn't show up in the GRUB boot menu if I remember, but it was a while back.

You might try deleting one of the *_linux_proxy files, and back it up first of course.  That should get rid of detection, as you suspected.  I would remove the second one, but they should be identical.

Comment: Can you say anything about possible reasons why this seems to happen very often? Where could this second file come from? And might you know a link to any official description which files the `/etc/grub.d` directory should contain and what the `proxy` stuff means?

Comment: I haven't yet been programed with the answer to that question

Comment: But on a serious note, I seriously don't know.

Comment: I just disabled the execution permission of the second one (`33_linux_proxy`), ran `sudo update-grub`, which displayed the Linux kernels only once, but on reboot, I was left with a GRUB menu *without any Linux entry!* Had to restore the configuration from a live session. So why does that not work?

Comment: I have no idea...